# Openmetadata Database Connection IP

Tags: docker, networking, ip

I installed Openmetadata with 0.13.2 latest release on the company network and opened the relevant ports. Database access has the following information.
"openmetadata will connect to your resource from the ip 84.51.27.125. make sure to allow inbound traffic in your network security settings." This IP is not an IP in the network and I could not find out how it was generated. I have to use the fixed IP of the server to access the database.

Where does Openmetadata get the IP to connect to the database or how does it create it? I would like this situation to be explained and I would like to access with a fixed IP that I set myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.